# Checking and compiling Protocol Buffers using GNU build tools

Tags: makefile, protocol-buffers, gnu, configure, autoconf

So I've this project which depends on Google's Protocol Buffers compiler and libraries. Checking for the libraries is easy as a `pkg-config` file is provided, thus the checking process is reduced to `PKG_CHECK_MODULES([protobuf], protobuf)`. Yet I'd like to check for the `protoc` compiler, or similar tool (in order to auto-magically build my `.proto` files).

Could anyone please provide some form of macro, or *good* tutorial on macro making (I haven't found anything useful so far...).

Julian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for the presence of particular programs, you should use either `AC_CHECK_PROG` or `AC_PATH_PROG`. See [the GNU Autoconf Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Generic-Programs).

```
AC_PATH_PROG(PROTOC, protoc, no)
if test "x$PROTOC" = "xno" ; then
  AC_MSG_ERROR([protoc is not found])
fi
```

See also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490978/).

Comment: Thanks, I had already figured out this a long time ago, and forgot about the question.